# Lake Formation Governed Table underlying format/technology

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-lake-formation

Lake Formation [anounced preview for ACID and RLS features](https://pages.awscloud.com/Lake_Formation_Feature_Preview.html). In the nearest future the next step towards [Lakehouse architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/harness-the-power-of-your-data-with-aws-analytics/) would be possible on EMR+LakeFormation without extra management layer like Databricks.

*What data format/technology is used by Lake Formation's Governed Tables? Would it be Hudi? If not Hudi, how the new format/technology compares to Hudi?*

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering as well, but haven't seen any information in this regard.

aws-data-wrangler is currently adding support for Lake Formation governed tables. Looking at one of the larger PRs https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/pull/560/files , some observations:

- Governed tables are managed through the lakeformation api
- An "LF Query Engine" is mentioned https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/pull/560/files#diff-71cf0e59c4ff5180dca21273da3998c16dcad442519db75af27482e5420f8dc0R61
- "Execute PartiQL query on AWS Glue Table" is mentioned https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/pull/560/files#diff-71cf0e59c4ff5180dca21273da3998c16dcad442519db75af27482e5420f8dc0R127